# maven cannot use correct version in verson range

Tags: maven, build, compilation, range, version

I'm using maven version 3.6.2 to build my project, it has multiple layers of dependencies and finally depends on ~/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/5.10/nimbus-jose-jwt-5.10.pom

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>[1.3.1,2.3]</version>
</dependency>
```

I got compile failed: com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:5.10 -> net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find net.minidev:minidev-parent:pom:2.3-SNAPSHOT...
If I manually update ~/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/5.10/nimbus-jose-jwt-5.10.pom to use `<version>2.3</version>` instead of `<version>[1.3.1,2.3]</version>`then it can compile fine. Why maven cannot interpret [1.3.1,2.3] correctly?

Comment: First why are you using version ranges if the fixed version works? Apart from that how do you define "correctly" ? Cause 2.3-SNAPSHOT is not a `2.3` cause a snapshot is before a release...

Comment: My project depends on some other lib which depends on this lib, I just test in local and update in the downloaded repository to see whether fixed version works. In product env, libs are downloaded from artifactory, it still uses the version range

Comment: If you test you should use branches to do that...

Comment: This is indeed strange. The range `[1.3.1,2.3]` should be resolved to `2.3` if this exists. If you need a fix for your project you can set the correct version in the  ´<dependencyManagement>` section. But it remains mysterious...

Comment: @khmarbaise If I understood the OP correctly, the version range is in **external** code that the OP cannot change.

Answer (score 2):

I use this to solve the program, refer https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/issues/388/json-smart-pom-23-snapshot

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
  <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
  <version>5.10</version>
  <!--参考https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/issues/388/json-smart-pom-23-snapshot-->
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```